# советы, как создать боковую панель

Tags: битрикс

столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно создать боковую панель, которая будет отображаться на всех страницах сайта. Но не представляю как это сделать, конечно я могу это сделать, но тогда прийдётся на каждой странице создать один и тот же компонент. Подскажите как сделать боковую панель на всех страницах сайта

Comment: посмотрите в стоковом шаблоне магазина. Вы можете задать доп настройку для страницы - показывать панель или нет, а саму боковую панель положить в включаемую область и проверять - если флаг установлен - выводить область

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вообще на всех страницах сайта, то почему бы не разместить в header.php или footer.php шаблона?